# Add an empty line at end of file according to PSR-2 on PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer, psr-2

I use [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for code styling my code.

When I inspect a file using Codesniffer most of the times I get the following error.

```
332 | ERROR   | [x] Expected 1 newline at end of file; 0 found
```

It's obvious how to fix this. What I need to know is if PhpStorm has a way to add the `1 newline at end of file`

I already loaded the predefined style from `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Set From -> PSR-1/PSR-2` and also used the `Reformat Code` to change the CS accordingly.

Everything is fixed except from the new line. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You already have two answers for how to turn it on for ALL file types in IDE (in short: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General -> Ensure line feed at file end on Save`).

In modern version (2020.3) that option has been reworded a bit. Now it says `Ensure every saved file ends with a line break`

[image]

---

**To do this for `.php` files only** you can do the following:

1. Install EditorConfig plugin (if you do not have it installed yet). In modern versions it is already bundled and enabled by default.
2. Create `.editorconfig` file in your project root (or whatever folder that would be where you want to apply such style -- it will be applied to files in this folder and below). If you have one already -- open and inspect it
3. Add rule for `*.php` files only -- property to use would be `insert_final_newline`

An example:

```
[*.php]
insert_final_newline = true
```

Links:

- [EditorConfig site](http://editorconfig.org/)
- [List of supported proerties](https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties)

Comment: To me did not work until I also enabled Editor -> General -> Virtual Space -> Allow placement of caret after end of line

Comment: As of PhpStorm 2020.3.2, I see this setting worded slightly differently: `Ensure every saved file ends with a line break`.

Comment: @KyleTolle Yeah, they seem to make changes in wording from time to time. Could also be that not everybody was understanding how that option worked...

Comment: Yes, the current wording does seem to be clearer and match what I'd expect.

Answer (score 15):

someone said picture speaks louder :D

you will need to tick the `Ensure line feed at file end on save` box

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In PhpStorm preferences go to:

> Editor > General

Check the box "Other: Ensure line feed at file end on Save."

Just realize this affects all code files you edit in PhpStorm, not just PHP files.

Answer (score 7):

Under Settings: `Editor > General` click `Ensure line feed at file end on save` is checked.

It will add a new line to EVERY file (.js, .css, .html), but it's the only way I've found, and it's a small hit for allowing PSR-2.